# _meteor_bootstrap_.require not working in Meteor 0.6.4.1

Tags: meteor, requirejs, node-fibers

The code I inherited use _meteor_bootstrap.require, an internal meteor details, to load module. Look like it's no longer working with 0.6.4.1? any suggestions of how I should load modules?

Current code
require = meteor_bootstrap.require
Future = require (fibers/future)

The error message I got: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:173
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at app/server/main.coffee.js:7:10
    at C:\Users\jhuang\Documents\Tervela\5.0.16\i32\lib.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:306:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.*.each.*.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at run (C:\Users\jhuang\Documents\Tervela\5.0.16\i32  \lib.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:239:7)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: Based on this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039352/how-can-i-use-nodejs-modules-in-meteor?rq=1, I checked and confirmed that I do have fibers.js and future.js under   C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [v 0.6.0](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v060)

> Packages may depend on NPM modules, using the new *Npm.depends*
>   directive in their package.js

Once included, package code can use `Npm.require` to pull in the module.

```
Future = Npm.require("fibers/future")
```

If you need to use this npm module in your app. Use [meteor-npm](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm/)

```
Future = Meteor.require("fibers/future")
```